# simplest way to center an element and have another one floated to the right

Tags: html, css, layout

Bellow is what I try to achieve

```
|                                 link | link | link             a,b,c search:  |
```

the `link-link-link` are centered, the `a,b,c  search` is floated to the right.
I try to achieve this using the simplest CSS+HTML

What I have:

```
<header>
<nav><a href="aaa">fff</a> | <a href="aaa">fff</a> | <a href="aaa">fff</a></nav>
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li><li>search: </li></ul>
</header>
```

I have `text-align: center` on the `header`.
I have `display:block; float: right` on the `ul`

Which almost gives me the right thing, except the UL is one line below...
I can solve this by giving negative margin-top to the `ul`.

Wondering if there is better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way: `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` on the `<ul>`

Comment: b.t.w. you are wrong about the necessity of the `ul` tag inside the `nav` tag. Check here http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-nav-element

Comment: Oops. Right. But since there's `li` tags, we need a `ul` or `ol` tag wrapping it, no?

Comment: yep, but those are wrapped in a UL

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `ul` an absolute position and stick it to the right like:

```
head { 
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

This would let it show up on the same line as the `nav`. The downside would be that it would overlap with the centered text should the user resize their browser to a narrow width.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `div` elements and to use `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to let the content of the cells aligned as you need. Something like:

```
<style>
.table-div{display:table; width:100%}
.table-div > div{display:table-row}
.table-div >div>div{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}

.l{text-align:left}
.c{text-align:center}
.r{text-align:right}

</style>

<div class="table-div">
  <div style="display:table-row">
     <div class="l">|</div>
     <div class="c"> link | link | link</div>
     <div class="r">a,b,c search:  |</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

I know, is not the simplest way, but will let the things to appear as you need even if the window will be re-sized (which should not be an advantage for someone).

Answer (score 0):

Threw together a jsfiddle to sum up all the above answers, including floating the list items to the left to get it showing exactly like your example.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonezy/qQGUQ/1/

```
header {text-align:center;position:relative;}
header ul {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
header ul li {float:left;}
```

Hope that helps.